# Iterate through JSON array: Get name of the parameter

Tags: jquery, json, loops

I'm iterating through my JSON response. I've got HTML elements with id's as the parameter names.

For example, my JSON response contains a `"costcenter":"1234"`, and there's a `<span>` element with the id `costcenter`.

Now, instead of writing a statement for every id, I thought I could iterate through the JSON array, and automatically read its name.

This is what I got

```
$(".dataset").click(function() {
    changeid = this.id;

    $.ajax({
        url: "source",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {
            id: changeid
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // How to get the name of the parameter, and then read it's value?
        }
    })
})
```

The JSON looks like that, it's just one dimension and 1 result set only:
`{"changeid":"1","costcenter":"478","manager":"John Smith"}`

Comment: your code isn't inspecting each .dataset element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question you want something like that in your success function :

```
for (var key in data) {
   $('#'+key).html(data[key]);
}
```