# Fetching the array value from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have the below object from where Im trying to fetch the required output. Result is the new object forming the final output

```
    var obj = {
        Customer: {
            Name: "emp1",
            Departments: [
                {Departmentname: "ABC", Members: [
                    {mname: "aa"},
                    {mname: "hh"} ,
                    {mname: "kk"}
                ]},
                {Departmentname: "XYZ", Members: [
                    {mname: "gg"},
                    {mname: "ff"}
                ]}
            ]
        }
    }


Required output:
{
    Result:[
        {mname: "aa", Departmentname: "ABC"},
        {mname: "hh", Departmentname: "ABC"},
        {mname: "kk", Departmentname: "ABC"},
        {mname: "gg", Departmentname: "XYZ"},
        {mname: "ff", Departmentname: "XYZ"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Just a question, did you tried parsing the json using JSON.parse and then access the values and creating the array. I am not sure where exactly you are facing challenge. Can you post any code that you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this one can help

```
var Result = [];
for(var i=0; i<obj.Customer.Departments.length; i++){
    for(var z=0; z<obj.Customer.Departments[i].Members.length;z++){
        var aNode = {};
        aNode["mname"] = obj.Customer.Departments[i].Members[z].mname;
        aNode["Departmentname"] = obj.Customer.Departments[i].Departmentname;
        Result.push(aNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can the same output be received if the object is dynamic?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232621/iterate-trough-json-array-get-name-of-the-parameter this post can help you for that